# Python return for another function

Tags: python, return, pyopengl

im working with PyOpenGL, and i want to make small RGB converter function.
PyOpenGL for color use floating numbers from 0 to 1.
So 0 0 0 - Black
1 1 1 - White.
Im make this:

```
def RGB(Red, Green, Blue):
    Red = 1 / 255 * Red
    Green = 1 / 255 * Green
    Blue = 1 / 255 * Blue
    return Red, Green, Blue
```

And im using him like this:

```
glClearColor(RGB(255, 255, 255), 1)
```

But i get error:

```
this function takes 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I can't understand how to return multiple arguments

Comment: `glClearColor(*RGB(255, 255, 255), 1)`

Comment: Why you don't call RGB aside, put its return in 3 variables, then pass those 3 variables to glClearColor? (`R, G, B = RGB(255, 255, 255)`, then `glClearColor(R, G, B, 1)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your function `RGB` returns tuple `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` you can use [asterisk(*) operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) to unpack it, like this `glClearColor(*RGB(255, 255, 255), 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `glClearColor` expects 4 arguments, you passed two: the tuple and and integer.

You want to unpack the tuple with the `*` operator:

```
def RGB(Red, Green, Blue):
    Red = 1 / 255 * Red
    Green = 1 / 255 * Green
    Blue = 1 / 255 * Blue
    return Red, Green, Blue

def glClearColor(a, b, c, d):
    print(a, b, c, d)

glClearColor(*RGB(255, 255, 255), 1)
# 1.0 1.0 1.0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your `RGB` function, but with how you call `glClearColor`.

Your `RGB` function returns a 3-tuple, which means `glClearColor(RGB(255, 255, 255), 1)` calls `glClearColor` with a tuple and `1` (2 arguments, like the error says).

You can use `*` to expand the 3-tuple to 3 separate arguments:

```
glClearColor(*RGB(255, 255, 255), 1)
```

This way `glClearColor` is called with each element of the tuple separately + `1` (4 arguments in total).

That is equivalent to:

```
r, g, b = RGB(255, 255, 255)
glClearColor(r, g, b, 1)
```